# Add multiline items to ribbon menu c# dynamically

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins, ribbon

I want to add multiline item to ribbon menu (Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonMenu) in my office add-in like following image. but I don't know what these items should be?

*RibbonButton doesn't support multiline Label.

*RibbonLabel doesn't support variable font styles (like Bold and Normal).

UPDATE: if these features are not supported, is there another component (say DevComponents, Telerik, ...) that supports them?

[image: multiline ribbon item]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not all ribbon features are available for developers. There is no way for add-in developers to implement something like that unfortunately.

You can read more about available ribbon controls and their attributes in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: is there another component (say DevComponents, Telerik, ...) that supports them?

Comment: You are not allowed to place custom controls on the Office ribbon.